# GLSL uint_fast64_t type

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

how can i get an input to the vertex shader of type uint_fast64_t?
there is not such type available in the language how can i pass it differently?

my code is this:

```
#version 330 core

#define CHUNK_SIZE 16

#define BLOCK_SIZE_X 0.1
#define BLOCK_SIZE_Y 0.1
#define BLOCK_SIZE_Z 0.1

// input vertex and UV coordinates, different for all executions of this shader
layout(location = 0) in uint_fast64_t vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec2 UV;

// model view projection matrix 
uniform mat4 MVP;


int getAxis(uint_fast64_t p, int choice) { // axis: 0=x 1=y 2=z 3=index_x 4=index_z
    switch (choice) {
    case 0:
        return (int)((p>>59 ) & 0xF); //extract the x axis int but i only want 4bits
    case 1:
        return (int)((p>>23 ) & 0xFF);//extract the y axis int but i only want 8bits
    case 2:
        return (int)((p>>55 ) & 0xF);//extract the z axis int but i only want 4bits
    case 3:
        return (int)(p & 0x807FFFFF);//extract the index_x 24bits
    case 4:
        return (int)((p>>32) & 0x807FFFFF);//extract the index_z 24bits
    }
}

void main()
{
    // assign vertex position
    float x = (getAxis(vertexPosition_modelspace,0) + getAxis(vertexPosition_modelspace,3)*CHUNK_SIZE)*BLOCK_SIZE_X;
    float y = getAxis(vertexPosition_modelspace,1)*BLOCK_SIZE_Y;
    float z = (getAxis(vertexPosition_modelspace,2) + getAxis(vertexPosition_modelspace,3)*CHUNK_SIZE)*BLOCK_SIZE_Z;

    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(x,y,z, 1.0);

    // UV of the vertex. No special space for this one.
    UV = vertexUV;
}
```

the error message i am takeing is :

[image]

i tried to put uint64_t but the same problem

Comment: glsl without extensions doesn't have any 64-bit integer types.

Comment: Have you tried to replace uint_fast64_t to ivec2 or ivec4?

Comment: BTW, you really shouldn't be using `uint_fast64_t`. Just use `uint64_t` like everyone else. The number of implementations that actually use a different type for these is basically none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unextended GLSL for OpenGL does not have the ability to directly use 64-bit integer values. And even [the fairly widely supported ARB extension](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64) that allows for the use of 64-bit integers within shaders doesn't actually allow you to use them as vertex shader attributes. That requires [an NVIDIA extension supported only by... NVIDIA](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit).

However, you can send 32-bit integers, and a 64-bit integer is just two 32-bit integers. You can put 64-bit integers into the buffer and pass them as 2 32-bit unsigned integers in your vertex attribute format:

```
glVertexAttribIFormat(0, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, <byte_offset>);
```

Your shader will retrieve them as a `uvec2` input:

```
layout(location = 0) in uvec2 vertexPosition_modelspace;
```

The x component of the vector will have the first 4 bytes and the y component will store the second 4 bytes. But since "first" and "second" are determined by your CPU's endian, you'll need to know whether your CPU is little endian or big endian to be able to use them. Since most desktop GL implementations are paired with little endian CPUs, we'll assume that is the case.

In this case, `vertexPosition_modelspace.x` contains the low 4 bytes of the 64-bit integer, and `vertexPosition_modelspace.y` contains the high 4 bytes.

So your code could be adjusted as follows (with some cleanup):

```
const vec3 BLOCK_SIZE(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

//Get the three axes all at once.
uvec3 getAxes(in uvec2 p)
{
  return uvec3(
    (p.y >> 27) & 0xF),
    (p.x >> 23) & 0xFF),
    (p.y >> 23) & 0xF)
  );
}

//Get the indices
uvec2 getIndices(in uvec2 p)
{
  return p & 0x807FFFFF; //Performs component-wise bitwise &
}

void main()
{
  uvec3 iPos = getAxes(vertexPosition_modelspace);
  uvec2 indices = getIndices(vertexPosition_modelspace);

  vec3 pos = vec3(
    iPos.x + (indices.x * CHUNK_SIZE),
    iPos.y,
    iPos.z + (indices.x * CHUNK_SIZE) //You used index 3 in your code, so I used .x here, but I think you meant index 4.
  );

  pos *= BLOCK_SIZE;

  ...
}
```

Comment: is uvec2 flat-shaded by default?

Comment: @user253751: That's kind of off-topic, as interpolation qualifiers don't apply to vertex shader input variables. But integer (and double-precision) types do not default to `flat`. But they can't use anything *other than* `flat` either. So if you don't specific `flat` on them explicitly, you get a compile error.